# Ionic 3 cards button is not displayed on the bottom right of the card

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I need to move the button into the same div of the price, but to be at the end of the card. 
Here is my card script:

```
<ion-card class="offersCard">
    <ion-card-header>
      <b>Name: Ali</b>
      <br />
      <b>DOB: 1994</b>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <div>
        <div class="floatLeft imgStyle">
          <img src="" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="floatRight">

          Required Task
          <br />
          Encrypt Data
        </div>
        <div>
          <!-- <h2>Price: {{data.selectedPrice}} $</h2> -->
          <button class="btnMargin" ion-button color="danger" (click)="buyPolicy(data.offer_id)">Take</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div>
        <div class="floatLeft">
          <h2>Price: 40 $</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

The current behavior is like in the image below:

[image]

So I tried moving the button's div into the same level of the price's div, with adding floatRight class to it, but it was near of the price and not to the end of the card:

### Price: 40 $

Take

And it's not even centered together at the same level:

[image]

I tried then to put them both inside the same div and move the class declaration into both elements:

```
<div>
  <h2 class="floatLeft">Price: 40 $</h2>

  <button class="btnMargin floatRight" ion-button color="danger" (click)="buyPolicy(data.offer_id)">Take</button>
</div>
```

And the result was the same.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-xh4qki) about it.

How can I place the button to the bottom right of the card and to be centered with the price div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recomend to ban `float` from your layout vocabulary unless you explicitly want text to float around boxes. For layouts there are `flexboxes` and `grids` with good support by the browsers.

I removed the floating css classes and an unneccessary wrapping div-element from your code and added flex-box element styles like this:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;  align-items: center;">
    <h2 >Price: 40 $</h2>
    <button class="btnMargin" ion-button color="danger"
            (click)="buyPolicy(data.offer_id)">Take</button>
</div>
```

Here is your [updated stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-chjav4).

There is an excellent [guide to flexbox at CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) if you want to dig in.

Comment: Thanks. But the price and button are not aligned together. The price is at the top level of button. I need to be with the same line of the center of the button

Comment: Please read the guide ;) it's `align-items: center;`. I updated the snippet and the stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

You need

`justify-content: space-between;` to align them and

`align-items: center;` to center them vertically

get rid of `flaot` as mention in other answer

```
<div style="width: 100%;justify-content: space-between;align-items: center;">
  <h2>Price: 40 $</h2>
  <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="buyPolicy(data.offer_id)">Take</button>
</div>
```

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-o4jme7?file=pages/home/home.html

[image]

here is [flex-cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/#justify-content) you can play with